# What does "Array.from() does not create an intermediate array" mean?

Tags: javascript, arrays

From [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), `Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg)`
has the same result as `Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg)`,
except that it **does not create an intermediate array**.

> This is especially important for certain array subclasses, like [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays), since the intermediate array would necessarily have values
>   truncated to fit into the appropriate type.

What does "***Array.from() does not create an intermediate array***" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decompose `Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg)` to

```
const arr1 = Array.from(obj);
const arr2 = arr1.map(mapFn, thisArg);
```

Two Arrays have been created since both `Array.from()` and `Array.prototype.map` do return a new Array.

`Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg)` creates a single Array.